# React Native iOS Linking with HTTP Scheme

Tags: ios, react-native, url-scheme, react-native-linking

I want to use deep linking with iOS on React Native. My URL scheme is `http` instead of my app name. How is it possible to make it work using this scheme. It worked on Android by adjusting the scheme and host in AndroidManifest file.

My Linking URL is `http://myapp.org/` instead of `myapp://myapp.org`

Here's how I did it in Android:

```
     <data android:scheme="http" />
     <data android:host="myapp.org"/>
```

Comment: It's would be very much easy to handle and manage deeplinking on react native apps If you could use Firebase Dynamic Links. #https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links. And you would be able to address your issue also using this library